# Undefined reference to 'rindex'

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am trying to export some C code for my application in Android Studio using the NDK, but I am having this problem in the compilation. Can someone help me?

Comment: no, neither me nor anybody else can, unless you show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rindex` is an old name (a *very* old name!) for `strrchr`.  If it looks like it's trying to find characters in strings, try changing all the calls to `strrchr`.  (Similarly, you may need to change `index` to `strchr`.)

Comment: Good answer to a poor question.  A reference to ***[rindex()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rindex)*** if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Steve_Summit Now I am having the same problem in setpwent and getpwent,

Comment: @TiagoCouto: `setpwent` and `getpwent` are totally Unix-specific interfaces for reading the password file to get information about user accounts.  I suspect you're going to have to rewrite that portion of your program.